# Checkbox issue in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

have an ionic template with a checkbox .The condition is that once the value checked , the value should pass into the user_filter array(user_filter array already declared and working well). While i clicked on the select box the console1 value displayed but the console 2 not , means the data doesn’t entered in the array .Does any one know the reasons! …

### Html file

```
<ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Non A/C</ion-label>
                    <ion-checkbox (click)="choose_type('type','Non A/C',$event)"></ion-checkbox>

                </ion-item>
```

### Ts File

```
choose_type(type: string, value: any, event: { target: { checked: boolean; }; }) {

 console.log('Inside choose type function'); //console1
    let index;
     console.log('Boolean value',event.target.checked);
    if (event.target.checked === true) {
 console.log('Inside ture value'); //console2
       console.log('Value checked true');
        this.user_filter[type].push(value);

    }
     else
      {
        index = this.user_filter[type].indexOf(value);
        this.user_filter[type].splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log('User filter array',this.user_filter);
}
```

Comment: Change `(click)` to `(change)`

Comment: it's not working @JosefKatič

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank  you guys for your answers. Finally i fixed it well , let me post the edited code for future reference.

### Home.Html

```
 <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Non A/C</ion-label>
                        <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="choose_type('type','Non A/C',$event)"></ion-checkbox>

                    </ion-item>
```

### Home.ts

```
choose_type(type: string, value: any, event: any) {
    let index;

    if (event.checked === true) {
       console.log('Pushed into array');
        this.user_filter[type].push(value);
       }
 else
      {

        index = this.user_filter[type].indexOf(value);
        this.user_filter[type].splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log('User filter array',this.user_filter);
}
```

Tips :Instead of (event.target.checked)  use (event.checked) for getting the value.

Answer (score 0):

You need not use the change or click event for `ion-checkbox` instead use the `ionChange` event that is given for ionic checkbox then only you will get the selected values.

You can get the selected value from `$event.value`. `click` event works but you will not get the value selected in the checkbox. You get `undefined` when you use click event that's why the console is not printed.

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Non A/C</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="choose_type('type','Non A/C',$event.value)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
choose_type(type: string, value: any, selectedValue) {
console.log(selectedValue); // Will be true or false
// Add your code here
}
```

Refer ionic documentation [ion-checkbox](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/)

Comment: Thank you. It works.Changed if condition into (if selectedValue = true), but it doesn't entering in the else box . Have a look on my code.